# How do I substitute my values in a post request?

Tags: linux, bash

I have links .php how do I substitute my values in all parameters using `curl` post?
Provided that I do not know what the parameters are in these php links, curl should determine for itself what parameters are in the post request and substitute my values.
If I know the parameter, then I can send it to the links like this:

```
while read p; do
  curl $p -X POST --connect-timeout 18 --cookie "" --user-agent "" -d "parametr=helloworld" -w "%{url}:%{time_total}s\n"
done < domain.txt > output.txt
```

And if I do not know the parameters, what should I do? How to make curl automatically substitute values into parameters? For example, the value: `"hello world"` provided that I did not know "parameter"

Comment: If the server doesn't tell the client what the available parameters are, it can't make them up out of thin air. It's your job, as the person designing the system, to make sure there's a reasonable way to introspect your API.

Answer (score 0):

It's simply not possible. `curl` is a client program and has no way of knowing or finding out which request parameters are supported by a server or which are not.

Unless of course, the API is properly documented and available as an OpenAPI/Swagger specification for example. If it isn't, you're out of luck.

Comment: and through which utility can I find out the parameters

Comment: @DanisVakik you can't. Read the source code of the server or check if the server application can export a list of endpoints and valid parameters. Try to find an OpenAPI documentation of the web service.